# how do i send a int value typed in a text-entry box to a mathematical expression?

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

my name is Vítor. I'm totally new in programming, it is my second or third day in self learling python. I'm trying to build a metabolical rate calculator, it is the first thing that i could iamgine to do, i know about nothing from python. Then, i did it, but only stay in text editor (im using vs code), if i change the value in code, and run, i get the right value in terminal. But im tryint to operate it by a GUI, and i dont know how i type a numeric value in a text box, and this value are changed in my writed recipe. Ill show all my code from now, sorry for the weird words and long code, i'm really new in programming world, im from B. Anyway, thanks for reading.

````
   import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

#FUNCAO DO BOTAO
def click1():
    typed_text1=textentry1.get()
def click2():
    typed_text2=textentry2.get()
def click3():
    typed_text3=textentry3.get()
####MAIN
#TOP LEVEL CONTAINER
window = Tk() 
window.title("Calculadora TMB")

#CONTAINER DE FUNDO
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=400,width=400, bg="green") .grid()

#CONTAINER QUADRO
frame1 = tk.Frame(canvas, height=200,width=200, bg="blue") .grid(row=0, column=1)

#IMAGEM

#LABEL
Label (frame1, text="CALCULADORA TMB", fg="red") .grid(row=0, column=0)

#CAIXA DE ENTRADA DE TEXTO
textentry1=Entry(frame1) .grid(row=1, column=1)

textentry2=Entry(frame1) .grid(row=2, column=1)

textentry3=Entry(frame1) .grid(row=3, column=1)

#SEND INPUT BUTTON
okbutton=tk.Button(frame1,text='Send', command=lambda:[click1(),click2(),click3()]) .grid(row=4, column=0)

#CANCEL BUTTON
cancelbutton=tk.Button(frame1,text='Cancel') .grid(row=5, column=0)

#OUTPUT TEXT 
output= Text(frame1) .grid(row=6, column=0, padx=0.8, pady=0.8, columnspan=2)

#VARIABLES
Massa_corporal=66
Estatura=167
Idade=66

#RECIPES
Formula_HB_Homem=66.473+(13.752*Massa_corporal)+(5.003*Estatura)-(6.755*Idade)
Formula_HB_Mulher=655.1+(9.563*Massa_corporal)+(1.850*Estatura)-(4.676*Idade)
Formula_Williams1_H=(60.9*Massa_corporal)-54
Formula_Williams2_H=(22.7*Massa_corporal)+495
Formula_Williams3_H=(17.5*Massa_corporal)+651
Formula_Williams4_H=(15.3*Massa_corporal)+679
Formula_Williams5_H=(11.6*Massa_corporal)+879
Formula_Williams6_H=(13.5*Massa_corporal)+487
Formula_Williams1_M=(61*Massa_corporal)-51
Formula_Williams2_M=(22.5*Massa_corporal)+499
Formula_Williams3_M=(12.2*Massa_corporal)+746
Formula_Williams4_M=(14.7*Massa_corporal)+496
Formula_Williams5_M=(8.7*Massa_corporal)+829
Formula_Williams6_M=(10.5*Massa_corporal)+596
Formula_KTG=(((((1.255*Estatura)+(0.928*Massa_corporal)-64.8)*60)/1000)*24)*5

if Idade>=60:
    print ((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams6_H+Formula_KTG)/3)
elif Idade>=30:
    print((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams5_H+Formula_KTG)/3)
elif Idade>=18:
    print((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams4_H+Formula_KTG)/3)
elif Idade>=10:
    print((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams3_H+Formula_KTG)/3)
elif Idade>=3:
    print((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams2_H+Formula_KTG)/3)
elif Idade>=0:
    print((Formula_HB_Homem+Formula_Williams2_H+Formula_KTG)/3)

window.mainloop()```
````

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: yessss, thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive the value from a widget, you would want to use the `get()` function. The `get()` function will return whatever is in the text-box. See this [page](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) for more from the documentation.

You should also see the example on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734153/pass-values-to-python-script-with-tkinter)